# Is it possible to force cellular data use in Ionic Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework

When working with the Ionic mobile app framework, is it possible to force the app to use the phone's cellular data instead of wifi data when both are available?

Comment: You can force it on Android, you can't force it for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android devices always prefer wifi data connection if both mobile and wifi data connections are available so it's not possible, but you can detect what kind of data connection device using and allow your app if it is a mobile data connection by using following plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information